# Install eZ Platform 15.12 ("index.php" file not found)

Tags: php, ezplatform

I try to install ez platform on windows. I tried to follow instructions till the moment when it says:

> https://doc.ez.no/display/EZP/Installing+eZ+Publish+on+Windows
>   The setup wizard can be started using a web browser immediately after
>   the previous steps (described in this section) are completed. It will
>   be automatically run the first time someone tries to **access**/browse the
>   **index.php file** located in the eZ Publish directory.

**and the problem it that there is no "index.php" file** (I checked in "root folder" and in "web" folder) :) 
Root folder looks the same as root folder in: https://github.com/ezsystems/ezplatform-demo

What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no `index.php`, `app.php` in the `web` directory should be your `DirectoryIndex` for the latest version of eZ Publish.

see: https://github.com/ezsystems/ezplatform-demo/blob/master/doc/apache2/vhost.template

You should also be able to run a PHP webserver with for example: `php app/console server:run --env=prod -vvv`.
Use `--env=dev` for the dev environment, `-vvv` is for being very verbose in the output.

Then you should be able to open http://127.0.0.1:8000/ez to test eZ Platform.

Comment: @Mdt, did this help you?